# Update a parameter in ajax inside a function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nextUrlArticle = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("{{ path('next_video_url', { 'id' : article.id })}}", function(result) {
        nextUrlArticle = result.url;
    });

    function getNextVideo(ext) {
        if (nextUrlArticle) {
            window.location.href = nextUrlArticle;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

And it never passes into the "`window.location.href`" which is totally normal because it's initialized with `null` and there are an ajax call which updates the parameter but as it's asynchrone it doesn't has an effect when the code is processed.

But I really need  to check if the nextUrlArticle is not empty, so i can't remove that check.
**The `getNextVideo` will be called by a flash video player at the end of the video**. (I don't have the hand on this part of the code)

How to make that check pass ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the flash video player calling 'getNextVideo' before the ajax call is returned ?

Comment: no, nevermind, my code is supposed to work, i just get inconsistency result, sometimes it works and sometimes not, so i'll digg somewhere else than the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i needed to place the `getNextVideo()` OUTSIDE the `$(document).ready(function() {` because the video player couldn't call the function inside the .ready

Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

After success of AJAX, you need to call the function for execution with updated value;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get("{{ path('next_video_url', { 'id' : article.id })}}", function(result) {
        nextUrlArticle = result.url;
        getNextVideo(); // call function after update
    });

    function getNextVideo() {
        if (nextUrlArticle) {
            window.location.href = nextUrlArticle;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't want the function to be called after the ajax called as it's the videplayer who will call this function when the video is over.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the video calls the method before ajax completes.

One way is to pass the nexturl directly while loading the page instead of getting it from ajax,  For example:

```
nextUrlArticle = {{ nexturl }} //django syntax to pass context vars to template
function getNextVideo() {
    if (nextUrlArticle) {
        window.location.href = nextUrlArticle;
    }
 }
```